Sending transaction from different locations parallel, benefits?
I'm curious if for example I have server in Frankfurt which I send transaction from and the validator is located at New York, will it be faster if I would have sent parallel the same encoded transaction from my server in Frankfurt and also from my server in NY ? (The server in Frankfurt will spread the encoded transaction between all the locations using GRPC and at the moment that the server in NY will get payload from the GRPC it will send immidately the transaction on chain also).
Does that approach will possibly land transactions faster?
Thanks.

This approach you're providing sounds promising. However, I guess it's also controversial.
For eg. sending multiple requests for the same transaction can flood the network with too many duplicate transactions. Your actions also could be detected as malicious by validators and other network participants. Not even saying about that it's not really resource-efficient.
If you're aiming for speed, I guess a much simpler solution would be using multiple RPC providers or one with globally located infrastructure. There are a lot of providers and I bet you know and even tried some of them. I personally use GetBlock and I'm pretty confident with the speed and performance.
